# How to implement anti-scraping mechanisms for my Amazon S3 based site?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I have a few static web pages hosted on amazon S3 that are very frequently updated. I want to implement few anti-scraping mechanisms like banning IP's which are making too many requests or making requests appearing to be robotic etc. I know nothing is fool proof, but I just want to offer them some resistance & make their job difficult. I understood there's a way to blacklist IP addresses in bucket policy, but is there any dynamic way of implementing this like... IF a specific IP is making....specific no.of requests per minute....then, ban it for specific time. Or something like that.

Comment: Use existing software packages that add this feature to your website

Comment: Which software packages do you mean? And how can I add them to the website as it was a static site hosted on S3?

Comment: Fail2Ban is one.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS service that seems best suited for this job is [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/), the Web Application Firewall.

From the [Security Automations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/aws-waf-security-automations/capabilities.html) section of their documentation:

> Bots and scrapers: Operators of publicly accessible web applications have to trust that the clients accessing their content identify themselves accurately, and that they will use services as intended. However, some automated clients, such as content scrapers or bad bots, misrepresent themselves to bypass restrictions. This solution helps you identify and block bad bots and scrapers.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this with S3, but you can ban [IP addresses that exceed preset limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/tutorials-rate-based-blocking.html) with CloudFront. Just set up CloudFront to serve S3 content and block direct access to S3. Your costs may reduce slightly, they may go up slightly, but it shouldn't make a huge difference to your costs.

Answer (score -1):

I never tried it but I think it is doable. It won't be an easy checkbox though.

Here is what you need to do:

- Enable "Server Access Logging" for your S3 bucket,
- Create a Lambda function and schedule it to run every x minutes (rate) or on a cron. This function needs to:

  - Crawl through these logs and count how many times an IP address accessed a certain resource (file or bucket) in an interval of time, or the IP address that gets 404 ...etc,
  - Depending on a threshold you define, decide if you are going to block that IP or not,
  - Modify your S3 bucket's policy (You can take advantage of Boto3 for that) and add the IP you decided to block earlier (NotIpAddress is your friend).

Comment: This is really an excellent idea. thank-you.